# I am unable to use crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am unable to use crystal report.

I have a file crystalreport1.rpt and a crystalreportviewer.

I am unable to create the object of crystalreport1.rpt.

crystalreport1 cr=new crystalreport1();  //not able to create object of crystalreport1.rpt

```
 //CrystalReportViewr1.ReportSource = ds;
 //CrystalReportViewr1.DataBind();
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Any errors? What kind of server are you installing on? development? production?

Comment: do you also have a class named crystalreport1?  Or just a .rpt file?  Because your code shows that you are trying to instantiate a class named crystalreport1.

Answer (score 1):

try using the relevant namespaces....

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
```

then you can easily create objects for crystal reports.